# Was there a flu season in paleolithic times?

Tags: virology, epidemiology, infectious-diseases, anthropology, influenza

In temperate climates, flu viruses rise and recede with winter. This is for a number of reasons, including lack of vitamin D production in darkness (which weakens the immune system), dry air (humidity causes viral particles to become trapped in water droplets and fall), and people huddling together inside when it's cold (increasing the likelihood of spread).

So, was there a flu season in prehistoric times, specifically the paleolithic (i.e. before 10,000 BCE)? The first two causes would still apply for prehistory, but the last one might not, since people didn't have houses to live inside back then.

Also, in modern times, flu strains are reintroduced to the northern hemisphere at the start of flu season by travel from the southern hemisphere, but that did not occur in prehistory, which might have stunted the spread of the flu. Another factor is the low population density of prehistory, which may have prevented the formation of viral reservoirs in human populations. There may also have been significant variance by region, considering this is still a factor today. For example, the flu follows a more complex and less predictable seasonal pattern in tropical climates versus temperate.

Comment: Edited, focused version of an old closed question that went unanswered.

Comment: Looks pretty much the same to me. What did you change? How do you know that migration from the Southern hemisphere didn't occur? Humans have been building shelters (wood houses even) for hundreds of thousands of years. So many suppositions stated as "facts".

Comment: I removed mentions of cold viruses (which are several hundred viruses, many distantly related) to focus on the flu, and limited the timeframe to the Paleolithic (which is more narrowly defined than prehistory). There was obviously no transcontinental air travel in prehistory, preventing flu viruses from spreading between hemispheres the way they do today. Houses were much less common before the Neolithic, when humans began farming.

Comment: The first transcontinental flight (non-stop) was in 1923, 5 years after the terrible Spanish flu of 1918, which went around the globe twice, almost 30 years before transcontinental flight actually started with three airlines flying (only the North Atlantic, btw.) Houses were far from uncommon; the ancient Pueblo people on North America had multistory-dwelling villages before 10,000 BCE. I think you might be making a lot of unfounded assumptions. People huddled in tents a million years ago. A cough in a tent is pretty significant.

Comment: This question is about flu season, not the Spanish flu. Even if there was not transcontinental flight in 1918, there was rapid long-distance travel by ship and rail which obviously was not occurring in prehistory. This would certainly have an effect on the circulation of flu strains. The Pueblo people absolutely were not making multistory-dwelling villages before 10,000 BCE; they did not even exist as a culture back then.

Comment: The flu (HnNn Type A variants) is the flu; it spread before air travel; that was my point. The Spanish flu was only a particularly virulent-for-the-young variant. You're mistaken about the ancestral pueblos, and the city of Jericho was a city before 9000 BCE (some scholar date it to pre-agriculture.) Why don't you add some evidence of research to support your claims? You're more likely to get an answer that way.

Comment: I'll wait until others add cited evidence of research to support their claims. I added reference links in the previous discussion, but no one else (including you) bothered to, which made it seem pointless. Where is your source that the Pueblo people had multistory-dwelling villages before 10,000 BCE? That is a remarkable incorrect claim.

Comment: Overall, to me, this question doesn't appear on-topic for this site. This question seems like it might fit on [history.se], as the question is *primarily* about history, as opposed to a theoretical discussion of transmission and virulence under specified, or assumed, conditions. However, I'm not familiar with the History site, so I strongly recommend reading [that site's on-topic page](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to verify that this would be on-topic. I'm also not a significant participant on this site, so my judgement that this is off-topic here may be wrong.

Comment: Flu, as we understand it, is zoonotic, which means it's from animals. In this case, pigs and chickens. I think it's well understood that the flu we know and understand today didn't exist until sometime after humans started farming pigs and chickens. That doesn't mean there weren't illnesses like the flu, just probably not the flu we have today.

Comment: @frеdsbend - Human influenza most likely was passed to us by birds, including migratory water fowl. [Here's an article](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/influenzas-wild-origins-in-the-animals-around-us/) for laypersons.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I still wonder about the importance of 1) domesticated animals (chickens, pigs, etc.) in *transferring* the virus from infected wild birds to humans vs 2) humans hunting and touching infected wild birds vs 3) those darn infected wild birds not wearing their masks and coughing on us in closed spaces and giving it to us directly.

Comment: @anon Pandemic flu, maybe, which is the topic of that essay, but they rightly say that's not at all a given. It certainly isn't true for H1N1, literally called swine flu because it came from pigs. Seasonal flu circulates among humans, and feeds back into animals sometimes creating pandemics in them. For example, 1918 flu created a pandemic in pigs at the same time, though which species had it first is not known. As uhoh's comment above hints, it's foolish to dismiss the likely impact pig and chicken farming has had on shaping modern seasonal influenza.

Comment: @frеdsbend H1N1 was around before the name "swine flu", which AFAIK was coined for the 2009 H1N1 outbreak in USA/Mexico (before this it was known as as swine-origin). The 1918 + 1977 influenza pandemics were H1N1. Some variants of it are endemic in humans and some in birds too. Swine are not the only sources of this influenza strain. Phylogenetics tells us avians are the source of all influenzas (though C/D??); and you can easily isolate virions from water where birds concentrate, so not to dismiss agriculture, but catching it from the wild is certainly possible.

Comment: @frеdsbend - I read a fair number of scientific papers on the origin(s?) of human influenza virus(es). The phylogenetics bob1 mentions is the study of the genetic material of the viruses in order to determine the lineage of viruses, i.e. the where and when of a virus. Human influenza virus is an extremely old virus genetically, is most closely related to the influenza viruses affecting the Class *Aves*, predating pig and chicken farming, predating agriculture, predating any written history. The confidence you have in your (erroneous) opinion is unearned.

Comment: @uhoh - your comment is funny and thoughtfully put. The evolution (happening now) of influenza viruses is very heavily studied because of the worldwide morbidity and mortality of the virus, and because of the terrible consequences of a novel avian-to-human mutation that has a high degree of infectivity (the nightmare scenario: a deadly pandemic like that of 1918). While I have no doubt our close contact with birds has resulted in the deaths of some, it has not (to my knowledge) contributed to any serious epidemics. Bat influenza is also a threat, just fyi.